# MDX how to count visited users in yesterday exist visit today

Tags: mysql, count, mdx, retention

I have a fact table to store user login

```
date_key   | user_key
20140701   |     1
20140701   |     2
20140701   |     3
20140701   |     4
20140702   |     1
20140702   |     2
20140702   |     3
20140702   |     8
20140703   |     1
20140703   |     4
20140703   |     8
20140703   |     9
```

I would like to make a MDX to count visitors visited a day, how many go back in next some days 
EX:

```
Date     DAU  Next1  Next 2
20140701 4    3      2
20140702 4    2      -
20140703 4    -      -
```

How can I make a MDX to count

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: How many users do you've : thousands.. millions ?

Comment: @MrAlias
I tryed:
With Member
Measures.[R Next]
AS
Count(Exists([User].Members, ([User].Members * Date.CurrentMember.Lag(-1)))
But heavy loading, can not display

Comment: @ic3 
I've almost 600.000 Users, DAU 6.000

Comment: What is meant by `DAU`?

Comment: @FrankPI, DAU - Daily Access User, I've 6.000 Unit Users access a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back, sorry. Funny I was discussing DAU concept last Friday. There is no direct way to calculate this, so we need to do a bit of MDX calculated measures.

I don't see another way as to iterate through all users, something like :

```
 MEMBER [Next1] AS SUM( [Users].[Users Level], 
                       IIF( isEmpty( [Measures].[MyEmpty] ), 
                            0, 
                            IIF( isEmpty( ([Time].currentmember.next,[Measures].[MyEmpty]) ), 
                              0,
                              1
                            )
                       )

 [Time].currentmember.next -> move to next day (assumes currentmember is day)
```

For each user we're checking if the users did connect today and if it's the case we check this for the next day.

The empty should be on a measure that quickly checks if the user was there for a given day. Not sure how a distinct count works on SSAS in this scenario (in icCube we don't care). A pity in icCube we could think extending aggregation to support vectors, so we could perform a faster version.

Comment: Thank you. 
It worked, but with my data, so hard to loading.

this is my MDX:
member [Measures].[Next1] as 'Sum(Descendants([Users], [Users].[ID]), IIf(IsEmpty([Measures].[UU]), 0, IIf(IsEmpty(([Date].[Date].CurrentMember.Lag((- 1)), [Measures].[UU])), 0, 1)))'

Comment: I can't help you on performance, maybe ask another question and somebody with more experience with your MDX server might help (you didn't told which one you're using). I could help you with icCube ;-). Not sure descendants is a good idea, if you're getting 600k